# cannot access library in java.base

Tags: java, libraries

So I'm using the library:https://github.com/Litarvan/OpenAuth

When I run the code after linking javadx

```
superclass access check failed: class fr.litarvan.openauth.microsoft.LoginFrame$2 (in unnamed module @0x689604d9) cannot access class sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www.protocol.https to unnamed module @0x689604d9
```

Any idea what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: Short-Term band-aid: Add `--add-exports java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED` to the command line. Long term? File a bug for that library and hope it will get fixed.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I dont know if your talking about gradle, but when I tried to build in gradle it was missing javafx so idk how to do that

Comment: It looks like the source code for that library has already been fixed (in [this commit](https://github.com/Litarvan/OpenAuth/commit/0c505816cc4450e1c73405dbe91cd5b864a00049) specifically), but they haven't done a new release since then.

Comment: Thanks @Powerlord Only problem is that to build with gradle it requires javafx when it builds. Do you recommend any good sources to learn gradle?